# How do i display uploaded images at different locations in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rails-activestorage, minimagick

First of all i'm new to RoR and still learning.

I would like to know how to display different images uploaded by a single user at different locations each.

For instance: if a user uploaded different images of a house(exterior, interior, top-view, etc) and i wanted to show them in a grid.

Currently this is what i have;

```
<div class="gallerygrid">
  <div class="gd1 zoom"> 
    <%= image_tag @house.cover_photo(500, 550) %>
  </div>
  <div class="gd2 zoom"> 
    <%= image_tag @house.cover_photo(500, 550) %>
  </div>
  <div class="gd3 zoom"> 
    <%= image_tag @house.cover_photo(500, 550) %>
  </div>
  <div class="gd4 zoom"> 
    <%= image_tag @house.cover_photo(500, 550) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

My css

```
.gallerygrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
    }

    .gallerygrid img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }

    .gd1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3; }
    .gd2 { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 5; }
    .gd3 { grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4; }
    .gd4 { grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 5; }

/*.img {
    max-width: 100%;
}*/
```

Per the code above, this is how it is displayed. As you can see, it is just the same image displayed in all the 4 grids instead of different images in each grid.

[image]

This is my method

```
def cover_photo(size_x, size_y)
  if self.photos.length > 0
    self.photos[0].variant(resize_to_limit: [size_x, size_y]).processed
  else
    "blank.jpg"
  end
end
```

> **UPDATE:** So following @Daniel's answer, i moved the method to a helper like this

```
module HouseHelper
  def cover_photo(photo, size_x, size_y)
    photo.variant(resize_to_limit: [size_x, size_y]).processed
  end
end
```

And then used this instead

```
<div class="gallerygrid">
  <% @house.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
    <div class="gd1{index} zoom"> 
      <%= image_tag cover_photo(photo, 500, 550) %>
    </div>
    <div class="gd2{index} zoom"> 
      <%= image_tag cover_photo(photo, 500, 550) %>
    </div>
    <div class="gd3{index} zoom"> 
      <%= image_tag cover_photo(photo, 500, 550) %>
    </div>
    <div class="gd4{index} zoom"> 
      <%= image_tag cover_photo(photo, 500, 550) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Now all the images appear to be in a mess instead of my 4 grid layout,

[image]

**How do i fix this?**

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over your photos, otherwise you will be rendering the same one each time. So something like this will do the trick.

```
<div class="gallerygrid">
  <% @house.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
    <div class="gd#{index+1} zoom"> 
      <%= image_tag cover_photo(photo, 500, 550) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And then move your `cover_photo` method into a helper.

```
def cover_photo(photo, size_x, size_y)
  photo.variant(resize_to_limit: [size_x, size_y]).processed
end
```

Regarding the `blank.jpg` image, I'm not sure what you want to do, but I think it doesn't make much sense to fulfill the grid with blank images.

Comment: How exactly do i do this iteration?

Comment: The iteration is done by the `each_with_index` method and you will get the instance of each photo on the `photo` variable.

Comment: Where can add the helper? I already have `house_helper.rb` in my helpers folder. Should i add the in method in it or create new one?

Comment: Also, can you explain why you place {index} in the div class `<div class="gd#{index} zoom"` ?

Comment: @Maxxx You're close! You should remove the repeated divs inside the `each_with_index` block. Just add one as the code in my answer. That will iterate over all the images and render them (one per iteration). Thats why you have all the images repeated. The `"gd#{index} zoom"` is a string interpolation and will be rendered as `"gd1 zoom"`, `"gd2 zoom"`, etc depending of the value of `index`. Btw, use `{index+1}` to match your `gd` classes. Take a look to this to understand string interpolation http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html

Comment: Okay, so I removed the repeated divs and it worked. But, I'm not getting the Grid layout style i want as shown in the first image of my Question. How do I get that layout back?  Also what do you mean by "use `{index+1} to match your `gd` classes" ? How exactly should I do it and where?

Comment: I meant that should dynamically set the class of each image on each iteration. That is why you would need to have the index like `<div class="gd#{index+1} zoom">` in the first iteration the `index=0` so you'll get `<div class="gd#{0+1} zoom">` then will be rendered as `<div class="gd1 zoom">`. For the next iteration you'll have `index=1` so you'll get `<div class="gd2 zoom">`. That way the classes on the divs would match with your css classes.